# having mutiple select in ONE line

Tags: html

I've been looking for a way to have multiple select option in one line but I just can't get it do. 
here is a snap of the code part:

```
<div >
      <p align="left" style="inline">Protocol   
      <select style="inline">
      <option value="1">value1</option>
      <option value="2">value2</option>
      <option value="3">value3</option>
    </select>
     </p>


    <p align="left" style="inline">Parity   
    <select>
      <option value="1">valu4</option>
      <option value="2">value5</option>
      <option value="3">value6</option>

    </select>
    </p>
    </div>
```

Does anyone has a hint how to do this ! 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Well, if you just put two `<select>` next to each other, they'll be in one line. Your issue is that you're putting them inside divs and p's, which add vertical breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `inline-block` to your inline css:

```html
<div>
      <label>Protocol</label>
      <select style="inline-block">
      <option value="1">value1</option>
      <option value="2">value2</option>
      <option value="3">value3</option>
    </select>  
    <label>Parity</label>
    <select style="inline-block">
      <option value="1">valu4</option>
      <option value="2">value5</option>
      <option value="3">value6</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: With that I mean the `style` on the select

Comment: Great to hear, have fun :}

Comment: You should be using CSS not `style`. It is bad design to style directly into HTML

Comment: For things like this it doesn't matter it is only one line, but thanks for the downvote

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and lazy solution is to display elements as `inline` or `inline-block`.

```
<div>
  <div style="display:inline-block">
    <p style="display:inline">Protocol</p> 

    <select>
      <option value="1">value1</option>
      <option value="2">value2</option>
      <option value="3">value3</option>
    </select>    
  </div>

  <div style="display:inline-block">
    <p style="display:inline">Parity</p>

    <select>
      <option value="1">valu4</option>
      <option value="2">value5</option>
      <option value="3">value6</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ymXwYE

I recommend you to read a little about CSS `display` property. Or learn how to work with `Flexbox` or any CSS framework like **Bootstrap** / **TailwindCSS**.